# I’d like to install and require “fs”, ”path”, and “js-yaml” in Windows 10 but only “js-yaml” led to "Error cannot find module "

Tags: node.js, npm, node-red

Nice to meet you. I'm a beginner in computer and these days have enjoyed your sophisticated Q&As here. This is my first question in StackOverFlow. Please forgive me when I use not common notations and unnatural English.

I trid for several hours to install external modules in Node-Red (Node.js ?).
I’d like to install three---“fs”, ”path”, and “js-yaml”--- in Windows 10 but my trouble is that only “js-yaml” resulted in failure although the others can be successfully installed and used.
　I tried the following command…

```
C:\windows\system32>npm –g install js-yaml
C:\windows\system32>npm –g install fs
C:\windows\system32>npm –g install path
```

These commands created the modules, but only js-yaml behaved differently from the other two. After adding appropriate keys and properties such as “ fs: require(‘fs’)” to functionGlobalContext in (C:~~~/.node-red/) setting.js, I tried to start Node-Red.
 When I commanded

```
C:\windows\system32> node-red
```

it returned the following errors only on js-yaml and node-red did not open. It ran successfully when I removed the term “jsyaml: require(‘js-yaml’)” from setting.js.

```
Error loading C:~~~/.node-red/setteing.js
Error cannot find module “js-yaml”
```

I’ll list reports which may be related with my problem.
*The other two (fs, path) created the folders only in the directory “C:~~~/npm/node-modules”, but js-yaml created another js-yaml file apart from there in “C:~~~/npm”.
*Perhaps I tried “npm link” command in each directory before install command. And npm link [module name] in C:~~~/.node-red directory.
*I downloaded external module (node-red-contrib-postgres) from github, which may have fs.js and path.js??
*It did not change the result to add “js-yaml” term into “dependency”  in (C:~~~/.node-red/) package.json.
*I add  C:~~~/npm.node_modules(got by "npm -g bin"command) to enviroment variable "PATH"

Comment: Thank you for your helpful tips. I could use all of three in node-red by `setx NODE_PATH "%NODE_PATH%;<path obtained by 'npm root -g'>"`. I didn't distinguish it from "PATH".  The second suggestion is a really simple way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you install them locally, not globally.

When you install npm modules globally using `-g`, they are stored under `%APPDATA%\npm`, which is user-specific, and to which Node Red may not have access, depending on how it's being run.

Have a look at [Running on Windows](https://nodered.org/docs/platforms/windows) under "Sharing Node-RED between Users" and [npm-folders](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders) for further info.

Alternatively, you can also put the actual path in `functionGlobalContext`, which may work for you. Along the lines of:

```
js-yaml: require(‘/the/path/to/js-yaml’)
```